# How to use Left Join in subquery SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to use left join in subquery in SQL Server. My query looks fine to me but it gives syntax error.

This is my query:

```
(
SELECT 
    FK_OrderNo AS LHNo, VendorName AS LHVendor
FROM 
    tbl_ShipmentAPAR 
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_vendors ON FK_VendorID = VendorID
WHERE
    FK_ServiceID = 'LH'
) LHBase ON PK_OrderNo = LHNo 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         FK_OrderNo AS DANo,
         VendorName AS DAVendor
     FROM 
         tbl_ShipmentAPAR 
     LEFT JOIN 
         tbl_vendors ON FK_VendorId = VendorId
     WHERE 
         FK_ServiceId = 'DA') DABase ON PK_OrderNo = DANo
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_ShipmentAPAR 
(
     VendorID int PRIMARY KEY,
     VendorName varchar(200), 
     FK_OrderNo int 
)

CREATE TABLE tbl_vendors
(
     FK_VendorID int, 
     FOREIGN KEY (FK_VendorID) REFERENCES tbl_ShipmentAPAR(VendorID), 
     FK_ServiceID varchar(200)
)

INSERT INTO tbl_ShipmentAPAR VALUES (1, 'John',123)
INSERT INTO tbl_vendors VALUES (1,'LH')
```

Comment: The ON clause should be inside the parentheses.

Comment: I had tried but still facing same issue

Comment: Looks like you have shared an incomplete query. We'll need to see the entire statement if you want our help.

Comment: If this is the entire query, then it is in the wrong syntax (it should start with Select).  If this is only part of the query, then you did not include enough of it to pinpoint the error (should at least start with the From clause).

Comment: If you provide sample data and expected results of that query, we can help you to fix the query or even to improve it.

Comment: Become a better coder and help you (and everyone else) find problems faster. Create a short but not cryptic alias for every table and use it when referencing every column. And though it is purely cosmetic, it is hugely annoying to have all table names begin with "tbl_" IMO - that does nothing useful and requires more key strokes.

Comment: Your left joins are logically converted to inner joins when you refer to the unpreserved table in the WHERE clause. In your code fragment, you reference `FK_ServiceID` from Vendors - which is in the unpreserved table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chris mentioned, the query is bit incomplete. I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM    /*--> Added new */
(
SELECT 
    FK_OrderNo AS LHNo, VendorName AS LHVendor
FROM 
    tbl_ShipmentAPAR
LEFT JOIN
    tbl_vendors ON FK_VendorID = VendorID
WHERE
    FK_ServiceID = 'LH'
) LHBase
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
         FK_OrderNo AS DANo,
         VendorName AS DAVendor
     FROM 
         tbl_ShipmentAPAR 
     LEFT JOIN 
         tbl_vendors ON FK_VendorId = VendorId
     WHERE 
         FK_ServiceId = 'DA') DABase ON LHBase.LHNo = DABase.DANo /* -->Modified PKOrder no to LHNo because PKOrder no doesn't exist in either of the sub-queries */
```

This query worked for me. Comment to this answer if something must be changed.